# How to allow devise users to edit their profil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a namespace called "backend" which is protected by Devise. 
I would like now to allow users to edit their profil.

So I created a `users_controller` in Backend.
Here's the `users_controller`code :

```
class Backend::UsersController < ApplicationController
layout 'admin'
before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @users = Backend::User.all

         respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
    end

    def show
    @user = Backend::User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

    def edit
        @user = Backend::User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
    @user = Backend::User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I go on `backend_users_path` there is a list of all the users. I would like to permit to edit only his own profil.
So I go on the Edit page : `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_backend_user_path(backend_user.id) %>` .
Here's the Edit page code :

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.input :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

And there is my problem : when I try to modify the email address, nothing happen. The update fails.

How can I do this ?
I'm quite lost.
Thanks by advance.

Here's the log file :

```
Started PUT "/backend/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-13 12:13:51 +0100
Processing by Backend::UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wWrUDh7LVWhP+P7OWO6laDWaCKInxk37AA2BPuQWAI4=", "backend_user"=>{"email"=>"grellazzi@laposte.net"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35mBackend::User Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `backend_users`.* FROM `backend_users` WHERE `backend_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mBackend::User Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `backend_users`.* FROM `backend_users` WHERE `backend_users`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "1"]]
  [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/backend/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/backend/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-13 12:13:51 +0100
Processing by Backend::UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35mBackend::User Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `backend_users`.* FROM `backend_users` WHERE `backend_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mBackend::User Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `backend_users`.* FROM `backend_users` WHERE `backend_users`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered backend/users/show.html.erb within layouts/admin (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Thanks for your links, I tried to modify my `user_controller` with

```
if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
```

But it fails...

Answer (score 0):

If nothing happens, that usually indicates a validation error, in your case probably a missing password or other data that is not part of your form but is still being validated. To debug this, output `@user.errors.inspect` to your logfile or look at  `error_messages_on @user` in your view.

In general, take a look at these guides on how to allow users to edit their (partial) profile:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: Thanks for caring about my problem. I'll edit my post with de logs and more information.

Comment: Share the error message please, it should be in `@user.errors`.